# TastyPie Foreignkey trouble

Tags: tastypie

I'm using django.contrib.auth.models.User model class with no custom code and i've the following model as well:

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
      xyzstring = models.TextField()
      created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The resource classes are as follows:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
         queryset = User.objects.all()
         resource_name = 'user'
         excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        filtering = {
           'username': ALL,
         }

class XYZResource(ModelResource):
    created_by = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = XYZ.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'xyz'
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','put']
        details_uri_name= 'id'
        paginator_class = Paginator
```

When i go to **/api/v1/xyz/** I get the error:

**model 'XYZ' has an empty attribute 'user' and doesn't allow a null value.**

The database has valid userids in the created_by column in the xyz table. IF i remove created_by line in the XYZResource, i dont get created_by attribute at all.  created_by will not take null values as XYZ objects are created by valid users.

Please suggest what should i do to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

Guys thank you very much for trying to help me out. Out of frustration i replaced "user" in the following line with "created_by" and it WORKED!!

**created_by = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=True)**

TO

**created_by = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'created_by', full=True)**

Comment: I really wish this was documented better in TastyPie. The docs have lots of examples and then fail to explain key terms or will reference model structures without ever showing the models. Really frustrating. Glad I found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the created_by field to allow a null value

```
created_by = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=True, null=True)
```

Comment: wouldnt that show only nulls instead of usernames? clearly bocode wants to see usernames

Comment: It is the same as a model definition. If null=True, it won't complain if the value isn't filled. That's what seems to be giving the error.